# i386-linux-gnu_EGL.conf: No such file or directory

Tags: nvidia, compiling, cuda

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and whenever I try to install some software like cuda, opencv..etc, I get the following warning:

> /sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_EGL.conf: No such file or directory

I went to the file directory and tried to open it , but it pops up an error:

> The link cannot be used because its target "/etc/alternatives/i386-linux-gnu_EGL.conf" dosen't exit.

I think because of this I am not able to install most of the sofwares and #include is also not working

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a leftover from a previous nvidia driver package.

Just remove the broken link:

```
    sudo rm /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_EGL.conf
```

But I am not sure this will solve the other problems you briefly mention.